# Highlight square brackets in IDE TeXmaker

Tags: texmaker, syntax-highlighting

I would like if there is a method to highlight square brackets when editing TeX code in TeXmaker like with braces (if cursor is beside opening or enclosing brace, braces are highlighted), see image.

[image]

I want this feature for editing forest code, so I can easily find missing brackets, especially in case of big trees.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  [VP
    [DP[John]]
    [V'
      [V[sent]]
      [DP[Mary]]
      [DP[D[a]][NP[letter]]]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can't see any option for this in the settings, so my initial guess would be that you need to make a feature request to the maintainer. Meanwhile, TeXstudio does this.

Comment: Both Texmaker and TeXstudio coexist very nicely on the same system using the same installation of TeX/LaTeX.  I normally use Texmaker due to the less cluttered user interface.  However, I regularly use TeXstudio for several of the very valuable debugging features.